# Instance variables of a copy of an object and original one

Tags: java, object, copy-constructor

Does a copy of an object (with `int` instance variables through copy-constructor) get the same instance variable as the original object? If so, I was wondering if the original object and copy objects are referencing to the same instance variables. Look at the example below, if I create a copy of an existing `BankAccount` do they both reference to same instance variables `balance` and `accountNumber`?

`public class BankAccount {
    private static int bankAccountCount = 0;
    private double balance = 0.0;
    private int accountNumber = 1;


    public BankAccount() {
        accountNumber += bankAccountCount ;
        bankAccountCount++;
        }   

    public BankAccount(double startBalance) {
        this();
        balance = startBalance;
    }

    public BankAccount(BankAccount accountToCopy) { // copy-constructor
        balance = accountToCopy.balance;
        accountNumber = accountToCopy.accountNumber;`

Comment: Primitives aren't reference types. You have distinct instance variables here.

Comment: Don't ask the same question twice. If you want to add more information to your original question, use the [edit] link under the question.

Answer (score 0):

The instance variables are **NOT** copied unless the variable is `static`. 
A static variable belongs to the class and not the instantiated object. In your case :

```
private static int bankAccountCount = 0; //Would all share the same value
private double balance = 0.0; //would not transfer
private int accountNumber = 1; //would not transfer
```

In order to copy the values over how you would like, you would either need to change the visibility of the values, or provide a accessor method to access the value.

So if you had two different objects, both with a static variable:

```
public class Example{

    private static int counter = 0;

    public Example(){
        counter ++;
    }
}
```

When you create a object of this class

```
Example e = new Example();
```

counter is now equal to 1

If we create a second object:

```
Example e2 = new Example();
```

counter is now equal to 2 in both objects.

Comment: This is only semi accurate, since **he is asking about what happens when he does copy them in his third Constructor**. However they are of primitive type and hence aren't reference and hence independent in the two resulting objects.

Comment: Valid point. Thank you for pointing that out. Editted

Comment: @J and Ryan: What if accountNumber is an object of another class